# Make HTML Input Area Readonly but Selectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got an input area that's transparent and when you click on it the glowing border shows up (intended) and you can edit the text. I'm trying to get the glowing border to still show up when you click it but make the text inside uneditable.

```
<input style='border:none; background:none;' value='TEXT'>
```

Adding `readonly` or `readonly="readonly"` makes the input act like an uneditable div, you can't double click the input area to select it all and the glowing border doesn't show up. How can I retain the input functionality without allowing the text to be changed?

Comment: What exactly does selectable mean? That you can select it? Copy it? That it shows a background on focus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the readonly attribute with some CSS:

```css
input:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px #3d94db;
}
```

```html
<input style='border:none; background:none;' value='TEXT' readonly>
```

Comment: Perfect, added the 'text' cursor on hover as well and it looks identical.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe give a default value to an input field

The default protocol when a user presses a key is to type in text. We can override that with `preventDefault()`.

Now, I just realized that you can circumvent this by using the mouse right click event. So another event listener is required `contextmenu`. Now, you can no longer cheat with this.

```js
var inputField = document.getElementById("input-field");

inputField.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});

inputField.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-field" value="This value can be selected" />
```

Comment: This will not work, if you enter the value with the mouse (e.g. pasting values). To prevent this, you need to catch the change listener and then reset the input field.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I completely forgot about the `rightclick` because I was so used to keyboard shortcuts